# Symfony's validator documentation outdated or bug for callback annotation?

Tags: symfony, callback, annotations, validation

I used [this example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#configuration) to add a callback method which gets called by Symfony's validator:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validatePassword(ExecutionContextInterface $context){...}
```

If I run this code I get the error message: **The options "methods" must be set for constraint Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Callback"**

After short googling I found [this](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/custom-validation-property-path#the-callback-constraint) where the annotation is before the class name like this:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validatePassword"})
 */
class User{...}
```

Now everything works fine. So I am wondering if this is a bug or if Symfony's documentation is outdated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're linking to the 'current' docs, which at the moment means Symfony 2.4. For Symfony 2.3 and earlier you had to put the annotation on the class, as you discovered.

Note the 'warning' at the top of your example page:

> *New in version 2.4*: The Callback constraint was simplified in Symfony 2.4. For usage examples with older Symfony versions, see the corresponding versions of this documentation page.

:-)